# Javascript slideshow background image go back to selected page image on hover out

Tags: javascript, slideshow

On this Wordpress site: http://www.2eenheid.de/cloud/ theres a slideshow with a menu. Whenever a user hovers over the menu item the background image changes to its accompanying image. When a user clicks on an image it stays on that accompanying image. It is also supposed to change back to the accompanying image when a user hovers over a different menu item (without clicking).

It does this in a way, but it remembers the last image it was hovered on instead of the page's accompanying image.

So in short:

1. When a user clicks on 'cloud' it changes to its accompanying image and stays on hover out.
2. When a user hovers on e.g. 'Webhosting' and then 'Unit4 multivers', the background image changes back to the accompanying image of 'Webhosting' as this is the last item it remembers.
3. It's supposed to change back to the 'Cloud' accompanying image, because the user is on this page.

Anyone any idea what I did wrong here?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var imgsrc = '';
            $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function () {
                imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');
                var newImg = $(this).attr('src');
                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': 'url(' + newImg + ')'
                    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                });

            }, function () {
                $('.pikachoose').stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'background-image': imgsrc
                    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
            <div id="slideshow-main">
                    <ul class="slideshow-menu">
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('supportenbeheer')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a title="Support / Beheer" href="/supportenbeheer" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-4.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-4.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Support / Beheer</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('implementatie')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/implementatie" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-5.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-5.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Implementatie</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('cloud')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/cloud" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-11.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-11.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Cloud</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('webhosting-en-hosting')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/webhosting-en-hosting" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-8.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-8.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Webhosting / Hosting</span></a></li>
                        <li class="<?php if (is_page('unit4-multivers')) { echo "current_page_item"; }?>"><a href="/unit4-multivers" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-2.jpg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/slideshow/slideshow-2.jpg" alt="2Eenheid"/><span>Unit4 Multivers</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly I think the problem is that you want to set the value of imgsrc after a click rather than before a change due to hover.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Oh I got it! I switched the line `imgsrc = $('.pikachoose').css('background-image');` above the hover function and now it works. Thanks!